# Make field unique based on a boolean field value with multiple column in grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am using grails-2.5.2 version. I have a field which I want to make unique based on two field. But if the `isActive` field value is `true` then it will have one row with the same `roll`. But if `false` then multiple entry can be saved with the same `roll`. My class is below:

```
    class Student {

    Integer roll
    String name
    Boolean isActive

    static constraints = {
      name(unique: ['roll', 'isActive'])
    }
}
```

Actually I want the unique like this - `name(unique: ['roll', 'isActive' == true])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I want the unique like this - name(unique: ['roll',
>   'isActive' == true])

We don't have any specific support in GORM to express something like that.  You will need to express that restriction in your own code in the app.

I am not 100% sure and it may depend on what databases you have to support but I don't think there is going to be a good way to express that kind of restriction in your database either.

Comment: Our business needs this type of restriction at this point. But no gorm support :(

Comment: "Our business needs this type of restriction at this point. " - It wouldn't be difficult to implement yourself.  You could do it with logic in your app or with a custom constraint.

Comment: First we used findBy properties, but it fails. Now we have used in domain custom validation but I was looking for grails provided solution which is not available right now